# Convert SMT-LIBv2 QF_AUFBV to CNF DIMACS format using Z3

Tags: z3, smt, sat

Can I convert an input file having SMT-LIBv2 format and containing set-logic QF_AUFBV, to CNF? If so, how can I use the Z3 command line unility to do it?

UPDATE: I also need the mapping of the variables from th SMT-LIBv2 instance to the CNF DIMACS file as comments. Is that possible using Z3?

Answer (score 1):

QF_AUFBV contains both arrays and uninterpreted functions. I don't think CNF DIMACS understands any of that.

From the programmatic API, you can apply the tactics that convert formulas to CNF. Then you can walk those formulas and pretty print them in any form you like. The Z3 source code also contains a few places where we dump intermediary results into DIMACS, but we don't expose ready to use features for this (but you can always compile your own version of Z3 for this need, e.g., use the "goal::display_dimacs" utility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've added a call to m_solver.display_dimacs(std::cout); to the operator function in the Z3 file called sat_tactic.cpp. However, when I call Z3 with the smt2 input file it only prints "sat" on the std::out. Could you please let me know where exactly I should place display_dimacs? Thanks again!

Comment: One more thing: Is it possible to also output the mapping from the variable names in the SMT2 instance as comments in the CNF DIMACS file?